# Xamarin forms - populating two async pickers error on re-load of page

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

the second is dependent on the first pickers electedIndexChanged event.

I need to set the source of each picker first, then set any user preferences so each picker is selected with the correct value. I've tried a number of ways but i dont know the best approach. Here is what i'm doing at the moment.

The methods used to populate each dropdown are async, so i have to do the following:

```
public UserPreferencesPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel = new UserPreferencesViewModel();



    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        await LoadData();
        await SetPreferences();



    }

    private async Task LoadData()
    {

        await viewModel.LoadPreferenceData();
        await viewModel.LoadServiceData();
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.UserPreferences.ServiceCode))
        {
            await viewModel.LoadTeamClinicianData(viewModel.UserPreferences.ServiceCode);
        }

    }
    private async Task SetPreferences()
    {
        try
        {


        var serviceCode = viewModel.UserPreferences.ServiceCode;

        ServicePicker.SelectedIndex = viewModel.Services.IndexOf(viewModel.Services.Where(x => x.ServiceCode == serviceCode).FirstOrDefault());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }


    private async void ServicePicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var TeamClinicianCode = viewModel.UserPreferences.TeamClinicianCode;
        //    //save preference
        if (ServicePicker.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            viewModel.UserPreferences.ServiceCode = ((Service)ServicePicker.SelectedItem).ServiceCode.Trim();
           var a = await App.Database.SaveUserPreferenceAsync(viewModel.UserPreferences);
            //Load Dropdown
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.UserPreferences.ServiceCode))
            {
                viewModel.UserPreferences.TeamClinicianCode = string.Empty;

                await viewModel.LoadTeamClinicianData(viewModel.UserPreferences.ServiceCode);
                TeamClinicianPicker.SelectedIndex = viewModel.TeamClinicians.IndexOf(viewModel.TeamClinicians.Where(x => x.Code.Trim() == TeamClinicianCode.Trim()).FirstOrDefault());

                var b = await App.Database.SaveUserPreferenceAsync(viewModel.UserPreferences);
            }
        }
    }

    private async void TeamClinicianPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //    //save preference
        viewModel.UserPreferences.TeamClinicianCode = ((TeamClinican)TeamClinicianPicker.SelectedItem).Code.Trim();
        var a = await App.Database.SaveUserPreferenceAsync(viewModel.UserPreferences);
    }
```

The first time the page loads, it loads correctly and sets the values. The second time the page loads, there is a null exception, but i'm unable to debug properly as its in the iOS Project

I'm using Xamarin forms with iOS

Thanks

Comment: If you are referring to navigating back as second time page load! then there shouldn't be any issue because it's retained in the memory. Take a look at Application output tab if you're working on MAC (Visual studio) or in the output tab of visual studio it should contain minimal details of the exception

Comment: I think the problem is ServicePicker_SelectedIndexChanged does not need to run on the page load, only when the user changes it. Is there a better design for this?

Comment: I doubt that can't be the reason without change in SelectedIndex the event won't be fired. Still i would suggest to follow MVVM -> Binding so that you don't have to depend on OnAppearing event and load data everytime.

Comment: you have a simple example of MVVM -> Binding with two pickers? I've tried but find it difficult to set one picker based on the other

Comment: this is a good example: https://blog.xamarin.com/new-bindable-picker-control-for-xamarin-forms/ But it doesnt show how the second dropdown is refreshed.